# Windows Server 2008 IIS6 SMTP With more than 1 FQDN

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, smtp, iis-6

I've tried researching this one, but I'm not having much luck on google.

What I have is a Windows Server 08 R2 with IIS6 SMTP installed and configured / working 100% perfectly for Domain A.

Domain B has been purchased, and is pointing to this same server, and IIS 7 (running the site) has been configured and working properly.

My question is how would I go about setting up Domain B on IIS6 SMTP so that mail can be sent from either domain?

I see that in the 1st SMTP Virtual Server I can add a new domain there, but in the advanced outgoing settings of the first SMTP virtual sever it only let's me add 1 FQDN. Am I missing something?

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0):

Use the same SMTP Virtual Server to send email for the new domain. I suggest setting up an SPF record for your new domain that states the existing IP address of your SMTP Virtual Server as a valid outgoing mail server. Follow [this](http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/content/technologies/senderid/wizard/default.aspx) link to the Microsoft SPF tool. It is a wizard that helps create the SPF synax to add to your SPF record.

More and more email service providers are using SPF as a method of identifying which mail servers are permitted to send email on behalf of your domain.